# unable to add a string to a rails generated reference number - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i am unsure why my method is not saving my reference number - your help would be much appreciated.

- i have a method that automatically generates a reference number
- when a reference number is generated i would like to add the string "JC" at the beginning of the generated reference
- eg: generated reference number: a3a8a957c8 and would like to have JCa3a8a957c8
- my code works correctly in the console but it dose not save the added string to the generated reference number
- when i call up payment.reference the string is not saved alongside with the automatically generated reference

> could one kindly advise me why the string "JC" is not added onto the
>   generated reference number

-

> model: payment.rb

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :generate_reference_number_main

  def generate_reference_number_main
    begin
      random_number = self.reference = SecureRandom.hex(5)
    end while self.class.exists?(reference: reference)
    ref_number = "JC" + random_number
  end
end
```

> terminal - console

```
payment = Payment.last
#payment details displayed

payment.generate_reference_number_main
#JC2dcbbfdaa2

payment.save
#true

payment.reference
#2dcbbfdaa2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
def generate_reference_number_main 
self.reference = "JC"+ SecureRandom.hex(5) unless self.reference 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the updated reference string to the reference attribute of the payment record before saving.

```
payment.reference = payment.generate_reference_number_main
```

Also, depending on how your code runs, you may have to watch out for this line

```
random_number = self.reference = SecureRandom.hex(5)
```

setting the reference value to a SecureRandom.hex(5) value before you save the record each time.